# Работа с коллекциями, stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Тут в консоль выводятся слова длинна которых больше 4-ёх.
Как можно изменить условие,чтобы выводилась слово с максимальной длинной ?

// main

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
public static void main(String... args) {
    Dataset.of(Arrays.asList("шла", "саша", "по", "шоссе"))
            .union(Arrays.asList("и", "сосала", "сушку"))
            .filter(s -> s.length() > 4)
            .map(s -> s + ", length=" + s.length())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
 }}
```

//Dataset

```
public class Dataset<T> {

private final Generator<T> generator;

private Dataset(Generator<T> generator) { 
      this.generator = generator; 
}

public void forEach(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    generator.generate(value -> consumer.accept(value));
}

public Dataset<T> union(Collection<T> collection) {
    return new Dataset<>(generatorContext -> {
        generator.generate(generatorContext);
        collection.forEach(item -> generatorContext.emit(item));
    });
}

public Dataset<T> filter(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return new Dataset<>(generatorContext -> generator.generate(value -> {
        if (predicate.test(value)) {
            generatorContext.emit(value);
        }
    }));
}

public <R> Dataset<R> map(Function<T, R> function) {
    return new Dataset<>(generatorContext -> generator.generate(
            value -> generatorContext.emit(function.apply(value))
    ));
}    

public static <T> Dataset<T> of(Collection<T> collection) {
    return new Dataset<>(generatorContext -> 
           collection.forEach(item -> generatorContext.emit(item))
    );
}   

public static <T> Dataset<T> dataset(Generator<T> generator) {
    return new Dataset<>(generator);
}
```

}

Comment: Что за класс `Dataset`? Откуда он?

Comment: Хотел спросить, что такое `Generator` и зачем всё это вообще, ну да ладно, предположу, что это не влияет ни на вопрос, ни на ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Что касается поиска самой длинной строки в стриме - есть встроенная функция `max`:

```
String max = Stream.of("шла", "саша", "по", "шоссе", "и", "сосала", "сушку")
        .max( (a, s) -> a.length() - s.length() ).get();
System.out.println("max = " + max);
```

так же можно использовать `reduce` (свертку):

```
String max = Stream.of("шла", "саша", "по", "шоссе", "и", "сосала", "сушку")
                   .reduce("", (a, s) -> s.length() > a.length() ? s : a);
System.out.println("max = " + max);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dataset.of(Arrays.asList("шла", "саша", "по", "шоссе"))
       .union(Arrays.asList("и", "сосала", "сушку"))
       .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
       .map(s -> s + ", length=" + s.length())
       .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```